# why does dereferencing a Box<T> not complain about "moving out of shared reference", when T is not a Copy?

Tags: rust, traits, dereference

As the title states, why does the following code compile?

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Foo {}

fn main() {
    let b = Box::new(Foo{});
    
    let pb = *b; //works
    // let pb = *b.deref();  // error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
}
```

The same does not hold true for a custom type with non-Copy target.

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Foo<T> {
    p: T,
}

impl<T> Deref for Foo<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &<Self as Deref>::Target {
        &self.p
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo { p: vec![1u8] };

    let pf = *f; // error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
    let pf = *f.deref(); // error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
}
```

Is `*Box` not doing `*Box.deref()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is `*Box` not doing `*Box.deref()`?

No, it is not.  This is one of those cases of compiler magic -- the `Box` type is a bit special and the compiler treats it specially.

Looking at [the `Deref` implementation for `Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1899) gives us a very strong hint that something is different:

```
fn deref(&self) -> &T {
    &**self
}
```

If this were any other type, this would cause infinite recursion, but the deref operator (`*`) is handled internally be the compiler when applied to a `Box` value.

One of the special things you're allowed to do with boxes is move its contained value out, which has the side-effect of destroying the box and freeing its heap allocation.

(Also, the unstable [`Box::into_inner()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_inner) associated function takes `boxed: Self` and simply returns `*boxed`, further illustrating this.)