# Moving value out of the Box by dereferencing (and what it is desugared into)?

Tags: pointers, rust, reference, dereference, syntactic-sugar

Consider the following code:

```
    let x = String::from("123");

    let bx = Box::new(x);

    let dbx = *bx;

    println!("{}", dbx);
    //println!("{}", bx); // error due to ownership move
```

Here `x` is created, later boxed into `bx`, and later `bx` is somehow unboxed in expression `*bx`.

As far as I understand, ownership of data is moved from `x` to `bx` to `dbx`, and data itself (at least memory occupied by `struct String`) is copied from stack (`x`) to heap (pointed by `bx`) to stack (`dbx`).

My main question is: how does compiler interpret `*bx`?

It does not look like [Deref for Box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Deref-for-Box%3CT,+A%3E), since this would imply claiming ownersip of value, having reference to value (`&String`).

It looks like compiler somehow desugars this to [into_inner](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_inner), but it is not obvious to me why.

So, What is going on here?

Bonus question: is there a way to see how code gets desugared, or how do I approach demystifying rust magic in general. Auto dereferencing involving various smart pointers is of particular interest to me now. I tried [cargo-inspect](https://docs.rs/crate/cargo-inspect/latest) but it does not seem to be helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you are right that `*` goes through `Deref` or `DerefMut` and only has access to `&T` or `&mut T`. However, `Box` gets special treatment and is allowed by the compiler to *move* out of a dereference.

There is currently no trait that allows one to do that for user-defined types (a `DerefMove` trait has been proposed but nothing accepted AFAIK). So there is no "desugaring" to be done; just `*bx` is what you see and what is left is handled by the compiler internally. It really is "magic" in this case.

You can see that it doesn't desugar to `into_inner` because the current implementation of that is to use `*` ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#605)):

```
pub fn into_inner(boxed: Self) -> T {
    *boxed
}
```

See also:

- [How do I get an owned value out of a `Box`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264041/how-do-i-get-an-owned-value-out-of-a-box)
- [why does dereferencing a Box<T> not complain about "moving out of shared reference", when T is not a Copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75846106/why-does-dereferencing-a-boxt-not-complain-about-moving-out-of-shared-referen)

Answer (score 1):

kmdreko's answer covers the language side, but in case you want to know the hardware side, I've made a couple functions that compile to the exact same x86_64 assembly as a dereference. These all read the `Box` pointer into a stack variable, deallocate the `Box` without running `drop` on its contents, and return the stack variable.

```rust
use core::mem::ManuallyDrop;

pub fn own_box1(b: Box<String>) -> String {
    *b
}

pub fn own_box2(b: Box<String>) -> String {
    // SAFETY: `ManuallyDrop<String>` has the same layout as `String`.
    let mut b: Box<ManuallyDrop<String>> = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(b) };
    // SAFETY: This `ManuallyDrop` is dropped immediately after.
    let own = unsafe { ManuallyDrop::take(&mut b) };
    own
}

pub fn own_box3(b: Box<String>) -> String {
    let p: *mut String = Box::into_raw(b);
    // SAFETY: `p` will only be used to recreate the box as a `ManuallyDrop` and
    // then dropped.
    let own: String = unsafe { p.read() };
    // SAFETY: `ManuallyDrop<String>` has the same layout as `String`. `p` was just
    // created from `Box::into_raw`. It is immediately dropped.
    let _b = unsafe { Box::from_raw(p.cast::<ManuallyDrop<String>>()) };
    own
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=82242ae17063f57c769211d1f96cea2d)